# Matlab: plot data from another script

Tags: javascript, matlab, plot, directory

Is it possible to include data in a plot from another script in matlab?

I have two sets of images which I have treated them differently in two separate scripts. However I want to plot the data from both scripts, on the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to accomplish this goal, depending on your workflow.

## Method 1

- Run first script, keeping handles to the lines/contours that you want combined later.
- Run second script, keeping handles to the lines/contours that you want combined later.
- Make new figure/axes, and copy the handles from the previous handles to the new axes.

This method is relatively quick to apply for simple figures.

```
    x = 1:10;
    y1 = rand([1, 10]);
    y2 = rand([1, 10]);

    % Contents of first script
    % I saved the handle of the line as l1
    figure;
    l1 = plot(x, y1, 'b');

    % Contents of second script
    % I saved the handle of the line as l2
    figure;
    l2 = plot(x, y2, 'r');

    % After running first and second scripts, I run a third script that copies
    % the plotted objects onto a new axes
    figure;
    ax = axes;
    l1c = copyobj(l1, ax);
    l2c = copyobj(l2, ax);
```

Alternatively, the first and second scripts can be called directly inside the third script, saving the user from manually running the first two scripts.

[image: Example of method 1. Blue line was originally plotted on figure 1. Red line was originally plotted on figure 2. Now they have been merged on the newest figure.]

## Method 2

This method will probably be more efficient if running the two scripts each time takes a lot of time, or keeping a handle to every plotted object is too tedious. For example:

- script 1 generates lots of figures, but only one of them is going to be combined with a figure from script 2; or
- script 1 generates a figure with 10+ lines/contours, and changing existing code to keep handles to each one is too much of a hassle.

In this case, the workflow is as follows:

- Run script 1, **save** the figure you want duplicated later as a MATLAB `.fig` file.

  - (Alternatively, run script 1 and save a handle to the figure that you want duplicated later.)
- Repeat for script 2.
- In script 3, load the `.fig` files and copy the line/contours from one figure to another figure.

  ```
  x = 1:10;

  % Contents of first script
  % I save the figure as 'fig1.fig'
  % Alternatively, I save the handle of the figure as fh1
  fh1 = figure;
  hold on;
  for i = 1:10
      plot(x, rand([1, 10]), 'b');
  end
  savefig(fh1, 'fig1')

  % Contents of second script
  % I save the figure as 'fig2.fig'
  % Alternatively, I save the handle of the figure as fh2
  fh2 = figure;
  hold on;
  for i = 1:10
      plot(x, rand([1, 10]), 'r');
  end
  savefig(fh2, 'fig2')

  %% Recover from figure handles
  % get handle to the axes of each figure. Assuming each figure only has 1
  % axes and no legend
  ax1 = fh1.Children;
  ax2 = fh2.Children;
  copyobj(ax1.Children, ax2) % figure 2 now contains the plots from figure 1

  %% Recover from .fig files
  close all

  FH1 = openfig('fig1.fig');
  FH2 = openfig('fig2.fig');

  AX1 = FH1.Children; 
  AX2 = FH2.Children;
  copyobj(AX1.Children, AX2)
  ```

[image: Example of method 2. Blue lines were originally plotted on figure 1. Red lines were originally plotted on figure 2. They have been saved and reopened, with lines from figure 1 moved to figure 2.]